# Where Kafka stores default Broker level configurations?

Tags: apache-kafka

Server.properties store only overrided properties but not all configurations.. Where Kafka stores default Broker level configurations?

Answer (score 0):

The defaults are stored in memory, inside [`KafkaConfig.Defaults`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaConfig.scala)